# Weird behaviour when renaming "Title" column in german site collection

Tags: list, column, rename

Today I experienced a some what weird behaviour when renaming the default "Title" column of a custom list. Note that im on a german site collection with english as selected menu language. The following steps were taken:

1. I created a custom list. As you can see, the "Title" field is named "title".
   [image: Field named title]
2. Now I go to the list settings, select the "Title" field and rename it to "title123". 
   [image: renaming of title field]
   [image: renaming of title field]
3. On an english system the title is now displayed as "title123". On the german system the title is shown as "Titel":
   [image: field named titel]

Why does this happen? Are there any resource files or something like that to change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because SharePoint Multilingual User Interface (MUI) translates also column titles. What you did was that you overrode the default **English** MUI translation of the Title field to "title123". However, when you switch over to **German** MUI, it will use the **German** default translation of the Title field. You would need to change it also on the **German** MUI side.

All default SharePoint field titles contain translations in the language packs you install. If you want to translate custom field titles, or modify translations as a bulk, you can export and import translations behind Site Settings, more details of that [here](http://blog.beckybertram.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=77).

Another blog discussing the MUI in general [here](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=366).